# Spring Batch-MySQL issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

When I test my spring batch (v4.0.1) app. with H2 in memory data base 
it works like a charm, but when I use MySQL it fails to run CommandLineRunner 
is there any explanation for this?

My POM file :

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
         <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:Mysql://localhost/myDB?useSSL=false
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=87654321
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Console:

```
    main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    main] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs
    main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
    main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
    main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
    main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
    main] io.nader.org.ScrapOneApplication         : Started ScrapOneApplication in 65.255 seconds (JVM running for 76.788)
    main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always]
    main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
    main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HDB, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
    main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.        
  2018-07-07 18:08:42.968 ERROR 780 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner                                                     
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@SpringBootApplication`, Spring's autoConfiguration is enabled by default. Since you have spring batch dependencies loaded in your classpath, Spring Batch AutoConfiguration is enabled as well.

During application startup, Spring Batch's autoconfiguration (BatchAutoConfiguration) creates a Runner and it runs all the jobs defined in your BatchConfig.

You can disable this behavior by either setting `spring.batch.job.enabled` property to `false` in your application properties or by simply excluding the Autoconfiguration for Batch just like as you did.

Please refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.html) for more info.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191789/6572971

Comment: "During application startup, BatchAutoConfiguration creates a Runner
and it runs all the jobs defined in your BatchConfig" this is the functionality
that my application is intended for, reading some data from file and procesing it, 
disabling this behavior defeats the purpose of writing the application

Comment: solution was using spring batch JobLauncher :