# "Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled" when run Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is error that I got when run Spring Boot program .

The structure of my project like the following:

[image]

`Student.java` just is model class

And `StudentRepo.java` I have

```
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{

}
```

`StudentService.java`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo st;
    
    public List<Student> findAll()
    {
        return st.findAll();
    }
}
```

And file  `TestServiceApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    private StudentService stu;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Student> li = stu.findAll();
        li.forEach(System.out :: println);
    }

}
```

When I run I get the error like the following

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-11 15:11:54.458 ERROR 22348 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
```

Please help me.Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe you can find some answers from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190952/failed-to-execute-commandlinerunner-spring-batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO there are some conflicting dependencies. Apart from that, there seem to be some issues on your code on:

```
....
@Autowired //missing
private StudentService stu;
....
```

And don't forget to scan the packages too.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.example.demo"
})
```

Comment: `scanBasePackages` is not necessary as all classes are under demo package, and main class is in demo package. So, there wont be an issue of component scanning